# Redis basic concepts of reading and writing

Tags: php, mysql, caching, nosql, redis

I have a mysql database with millions of records in it. and I want to use Redis to improve performance. I've already read about Redis and some of it's commands.
But I can't get how redis works. I mean, as far as I know,  I can use Redis to cache MySQL data. But how Redis will know about new records since it's last cached time. ( I think Redis also will fetch data from mysql to cache them - so it is a select from mysql )

foreach insertion in mysql, redis also should be updated, I can't figure it out what is the difference between selecting from mysql directly while Redis is also selecting from mysql to update itself. ( I don't know how Redis works, but I think it works this way )

Could someone explain how Redis cache works?

Comment: You have misunderstood Redis. There is no link between Redis and MySQL. Your application can choose to store some data in each if that helps with memory limitations of Redis, but that's a function of your application, not a feature of Redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application code will have to update Redis as well as MySQL.  You do this by calling **SET** to store new data by a string key.  You then fetch this same data with the **GET** command.

You can think of Redis as a cache, but it's true benefits are in it's data structures that allow you essentially modify the cache live.  These work well for simple lists/sets. Webscale systems that utilize Redis often use Redis as their only system that their web-facing application code will call. MySQL and other RDMBS are just for reporting data or historical archiving.

Answer (score 2):

One option is what's called Write Through Caching.  In this case the application updates Redis and Mysql with the same write data at the same time so no matter where the data displayed comes from (Redis/Mysql updating Redis) the data is always equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In your case its better to consider Memcached backed by Mysql db. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ha-memcached.html

But please note, Redis and Memcached are only good for key-value retrieval/storage.

Comment: so memcache also cache data, assume it cache a user's friends and one minute after it, an update changes that user's friends list. so how memcached knows if there is any new data? memcached will return it's own cached friend list. how does it know, there is an update in mysql?

Comment: for example: for a website like facebook. it's database will update every milisecond! so memcached should fetch every milisecond to be updated!! I can't get it ...

Comment: If you want to use cache with mysql then you must bear with "eventual consistency" and data expiration. You can customize the cache mechanism to refresh the data every X seconds. Other option would be vice-versa, read and write data in Redis but do enable the persistance logs.. and synchronize with mysql database every X seconds.